# Pandas частично удаляет содержимое ячеек в произвольном порядке

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1')
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='processing')
```

Данный код считывает один лист эксель файла и копирует все данные в соседний лист, но при сравнении этих листов выясняется что часть информации утеряна как в исходом листе, так и в новом листе. И каждый раз при выполнении кода затирается разное количество информации.

Но как такое возможно? Если в коде есть четкая команда **прочитать первый лист** - что заставляет его меняться? Эти же вопросы и к записи нового листа.

Ниже на скрине показывается три разных ячейки с симптомами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую версии: Pandas - 1.4.4, Openpyxl - 3.0.10

Интересные наблюдения. Данная проблема у меня проявляется при использовании Jupyter Notebook, но в Pycharm работает хорошо. Отправил другу программисту. Он сказал, что дело походу не только в Jupyter Notebook т.к. у него баг вылез в другой программе (я не уточнил в какой).

Пробовал на 4 разных компьютерах и везде одна и та же проблема. Так же экспериментировал с самой таблицей. Копировал данные в новую таблицу, менял формат ячеек и прочее. Проблема остается.

Моё подозрение, что код как то не верно реагирует на символы, которые есть в тексте т.к. этот текст с тегами. В начальном варианте было много столбцов, но проблемный только один - который в примере. Но я любитель, и высказываю лишь свои предположения т.к. мои варианты решения закончились.

В обязательном порядке выкладываю виновника торжества. Его величество [исходный Excel файл.](https://dropmefiles.com/AXUvx)

Спасите, помогите. Устал бороться с проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуйте

```py
from html import unescape
from unicodedata import normalize
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    'file.xlsx',
    engine='openpyxl',
    converters={
        'Описание - Description': lambda x: normalize('NFKC', unescape(x))
    }
)

with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='processing')
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: @torsaf, попробуйте сохранить в json и там посмотрите.

Comment: напомню, что я начинающий юзер и многого не знаю. Преобразовал в json, и увидел, что все символы кириллицы закодированы. Прогнал через онлайн декодер и проверил. Все скопировалось в json исправно. Но это не дает мне никаких новых данных, как быть в моём случае.

Comment: Методом исключения понял, что если убрать движок openpyxl, то все работает как надо, но при этом не работает режим append. Как обойтись без openpyxl но записать в соседнюю вкладку? Уважаемый @Namerek, так я и не понял почему ваш код не работает. Нужны пояснения, если не затруднит. На вашем ПК проблема решается вашим кодом?

Comment: @torsaf, проблема у меня не воспроизводится и с вашим кодом, код, который я дал, всего лишь исключает возможность появления escape символов наличие которых Вы предположили. Более того, если `json` отображается корректно, то Ваш код работает абсолютно правильно и проблема заключается в `excel`. Для очистки совести попробуйте открыть сохраняемый файл в `LibreOffice Calc`.

Comment: LibreOffice Calc даёт такой же результат. Переустановка Excel тоже не помогла. Как то все связано с openpyxl. Если его убрать то все ок, но функционала для моих задач не достаточно.

Comment: @torsaf, попробуйте в качестве движка `xlrd`

Comment: xlrd - считывает и с этим проблем нет. а xlwt - записывает, но в документации пандас сказано, что "Устарело, начиная с версии 1.2.0: поскольку пакет xlwt больше не поддерживается, xlwtдвижок будет удален в будущей версии pandas."

Comment: @torsaf, тогда могу посоветовать написать багрепорт разрабам `openpyxl` раз без нее никак